# Passar Valores PHP-MYSQL para Modal

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, modal

tenho o seguinte problema, preciso enviar para o Modal dados vindos do Banco de Dados, Vejam abaixo minha tela e meu código.

```
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Foto</th>
                    <th>SKU</th>
                    <th>Nome Produto</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Quantidade</th>
                    <th>Fornecedor</th>
                    <th><a href="produtoCadastro.php?id=0" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>&nbsp;Cadastrar Novo Produto</a></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    include 'conexao.php';
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM estoque ORDER BY id_estoque";
                    $busca = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

                    while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($busca)) {
                        $id_estoque  =  $array['id_estoque'];
                        $skuproduto  =  $array['skuproduto'];
                        $nomeproduto =  $array['nomeproduto'];
                        $categoria   =  $array['categoria'];
                        $quantidade  =  $array['quantidade'];
                        $fornecedor  =  $array['fornecedor'];

                    ?>
                        <td class="text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="<?php echo $id_estoque['id_estoque'];?>" data-nome="<?php echo $nomeproduto['nomeproduto'];?>"><i class="far fa-image"></i></button></td>
                        <td><?php echo $skuproduto  ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $nomeproduto ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $categoria   ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $quantidade  ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $fornecedor  ?></td>

                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="color:white" href="editarProduto.php?id=<?php echo $id_estoque ?>" role="button"><i class="far fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Editar</a>
                            <?php echo ("<a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='color:white' href='javascript:excluirProduto($id_estoque)' role='button'><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></i>&nbsp;Excluir</a>") ?>
                        </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                
                <div class="modal-header">                    
                    <h4><?php echo $skuproduto ?></h4>                    
                </div>
               

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="img/logo.png"" class=" rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="..." style="width:200px">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {                                                      
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
        var recipientId    = button.data('id')                                                                 
        var recipientNome = button.data('nome') 
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('#id').val(recipientId) 
        modal.find('#nome').val(recipientNome)
    })
</script>
```

[image: Essa é minha tela, onde possuo um cadastro de produtos]

Essa é minha tela, onde possuo um cadastro de produtos, no botão foto é aberto o meu modal, nele preciso recuperar o id do produto, nome do produto e a foto do produto. Lembrando que ainda não preparei o meu banco para o cadastro da foto

[image: modal]

Então em meu modal preciso trazer a foto junto com o nome do produto, atualmente meu código está buscando dados do ultimo registro do meu banco.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Que valores que vc quer passar para o modal? Eles já estão na sua tabela? Pq se já estiverem o problema é um, mas se for preciso fazer uma nova consulta à base de dados o problema é completamente diferente.

Comment: Eu quero passa o nome do produto e a foto. O nome do produto ja está em minha tabela porém a foto ainda não está. Do jeito que fiz ele está retornando o ultimo registro do meu banco e eu preciso que ele traga o registro referente ao que eu cliquei